# openssl_encrypt() randomly fails - IV passed is only ${x} bytes long, cipher expects an IV of precisely 16 bytes

Tags: php, encryption, aes, encryption-symmetric, php-openssl

This is the code I use to encrypt/decrypt the data:

```php
// Set the method
$method = 'AES-128-CBC';

// Set the encryption key
$encryption_key = 'myencryptionkey';

// Generet a random initialisation vector
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($method));

// Define the date to be encrypted
$data = "Encrypt me, please!";

var_dump("Before encryption: $data");

// Encrypt the data
$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, $method, $encryption_key, 0, $iv);

var_dump("Encrypted: ${encrypted}");

// Append the vector at the end of the encrypted string
$encrypted = $encrypted . ':' . $iv;

// Explode the string using the `:` separator.
$parts = explode(':', $encrypted);

// Decrypt the data
$decrypted = openssl_decrypt($parts[0], $method, $encryption_key, 0, $parts[1]);

var_dump("Decrypted: ${decrypted}");
```

It ususaly works fine, but sometimes (1 in 10 or even less often) it fails. When it fails than the text is only partially encrypted:

This is the error message when it happens:

```
Warning: openssl_decrypt(): IV passed is only 10 bytes long, cipher expects an IV of precisely 16 bytes, padding with \0
```

And when it happens the encrypted text looks like:

```
Encrypt me���L�se!
```

I thought that it might be caused by a bug in PHP, but I've tested on different hosts: PHP 7.0.6 and PHP 5.6. I've also tried multiple online PHP parsers like phpfidle.org or 3v4l.org.

It seems that `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` not always returns a string of a proper length, but I have no idea why.

Here's the sample: https://3v4l.org/RZV8d

Keep on refreshing the page, you'll get the error at some point.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you generate a random IV, you get [*raw binary*](https://3v4l.org/ookl5). There's a nonzero chance that the binary strings will contain a `:` or `\0` character, which you're using to separate the IV from the ciphertext. Doing so makes `explode()` give you a shorter string. Demo: https://3v4l.org/3ObfJ

The trivial solution would be to add base64 encoding/decoding to this process.

---

That said, [please don't roll your own crypto](http://www.cryptofails.com/post/75204435608/write-crypto-code-dont-publish-it). In particular, [unauthenticated encryption is dangerous](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/using-encryption-and-authentication-correctly) and [there are already secure libraries that solve this problem](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/11/choosing-right-cryptography-library-for-your-php-project-guide).

Instead of writing your own, consider just using [defuse/php-encryption](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption). This is the safe choice.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Now, at least, I know what caused the issue, but still I'm not sure how to solve it. 

If I replace:

`$iv =         openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($method));`

with:

`$iv =         base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($method)));`

Then the string length will not be 16 bytes long. `openssl_encrypt` expects it to be 16 bytes long (In case of AES-128-CBC method).

Did I miss something?

Comment: You don't encode it before you pass it to `openssl_encrypt()`, you change `$encrypted = $encrypted . ':' . $iv;` to `$encrypted = $encrypted . ':' . base64_encode($iv);`

Comment: OMG, so easy. thank you very much! Works like a charm. I've also wrapped  the whole encrypted data in base64_encode() in order to make it URL-friendly (like @Ryan Vincent said.).

I've updated the original post.

Comment: Hi!,  $IV_64 = 'AAAAAAAAABBBBAAAAAAAA==' ;
" is only 15 bytes long, cipher expects an IV of precisely 16 bytes, padding with \0 in " When I'm calling open_ssl encrypt with base64_decode($IV_64)

Means that the original IV is not 16 bytes long?

Answer (score 1):

### Here's the solution

I've updated the code from the first post and wrapped it in a class. This is fixed code based on the solution provided by **Scott Arciszewski**.

```php
class Encryptor
{

    /**
     * Holds the Encryptor instance
     * @var Encryptor
     */
    private static $instance;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $method;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $key;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $separator;

    /**
     * Encryptor constructor.
     */
    private function __construct()
    {
        $app = App::getInstance();
        $this->method = $app->getConfig('encryption_method');
        $this->key = $app->getConfig('encryption_key');
        $this->separator = ':';
    }

    private function __clone()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Returns an instance of the Encryptor class or creates the new instance if the instance is not created yet.
     * @return Encryptor
     */
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (self::$instance === null) {
            self::$instance = new Encryptor();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    /**
     * Generates the initialization vector
     * @return string
     */
    private function getIv()
    {
        return openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($this->method));
    }

    /**
     * @param string $data
     * @return string
     */
    public function encrypt($data)
    {
        $iv = $this->getIv();
        return base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($data, $this->method, $this->key, 0, $iv) . $this->separator . base64_encode($iv));
    }

    /**
     * @param string $dataAndVector
     * @return string
     */
    public function decrypt($dataAndVector)
    {
        $parts = explode($this->separator, base64_decode($dataAndVector));
        // $parts[0] = encrypted data
        // $parts[1] = initialization vector
        return openssl_decrypt($parts[0], $this->method, $this->key, 0, base64_decode($parts[1]));
    }

}
```

#### Usage

```php
$encryptor = Encryptor::getInstance();

$encryptedData = $encryptor->encrypt('Encrypt me please!');
var_dump($encryptedData);

$decryptedData = $encryptor->decrypt($encryptedData);
var_dump($decryptedData);
```

Comment: This is still vulnerable to chosen-ciphertext attacks.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me also. I got error like

```
openssl_decrypt(): IV passed is only 14 bytes long, cipher expects an IV of precisely 16 bytes, padding with \0
```

I was using lowercase method like `openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-128-cbc')`

Lowercase aes-***-*** method gives a result of length which varies between 12 to 16. Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-cipher-iv-length.php

Making the method to uppercase `openssl_cipher_iv_length('AES-128-CBC')` will give consistent value which is 16.

So while encrypting & decrypting the IV length stays the same as 16.